# Http-handler load error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, httphandler

I successfully added and configured HttpHandler in an Asp.Net **WebApplication**, but facing problems while trying to add same HttpHandler to Asp.Net **WebSite**. I have registered it in the web.config, am i missing something

This is the error I am getting

```
 Configuration Error

    Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyHandler'.

    Line 98:     </pages>
    Line 99:     <httpHandlers>
    Line 100:      <add verb="*" path="*.result" type="MyHandler"/>
    Line 101:      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
```

Here is handler

```
public class MyHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**NOTE:** I have not made any request for the handler via url, it is just not letting me run application.

Thanks

Comment: Is this in a web site project? It the MyHandler class in the App_Code folder if so?

If MyHandler is in a certain namespace and/or in a different assembly, you'll need to put the full name of the type in your "add" element.

Comment: I have put it in the root dir to avoid such problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**  I missed the WebSite at first:

Put the .cs in App_code and use this:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.result" type="MyHandler, App_Code"/>
```

Comment: In WepApplication it is loaded even without any path like it is in Engine.Handlers.MyHandler ,  but I have just added MyHandler in web.cinfig and it works

Comment: @Asad - I re-read, missed the vital **WebSite**...try the new answer above, it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked. Any thoughts, why is it not recognized out side App_Code folder. Why is this different for WebSite ?

Comment: @Asad - Just because you don't know what the resulting dll name was...if you look under your framework folder under windows, then temporary internet files you can find it.  Inside App_Code though, all the code there gets compiled into an App_Code.dll, so the assembly name is predictable and usable in the web.confg.  It's different because all code in a Web Application goes into a single, specified DLL name, so that's predictable as well.

Comment: Did this really work for anyone. If I do this, I get the error "Could not load type 'MyHandler' from assembly 'App_Code'." It's exactly the same error I get without this change, except it says it's trying to load it from an assembly called App_Code.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the fully-qualified type name in your type attribute, including the assembly name. Like this:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.result" type="Namespace.MyHandler,AssemblyName" />
```

Comment: And how do we know what the assembly name is for our website? (Or were you just assuming the HTTP handler had its own assembly?)

Comment: @Jonathan If you're running .NET code, it has an assembly name. Unfortunately, without knowing more details it is difficult to tell you exactly how to get the assembly name for _your_ web site. http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+get+assembly+name

Comment: I just got this working with ASP.NET 4.0 and IIS7. All I needed was the handler in a CS file and `type="MyHandler"` for the type in the `<system.webServer>` section. Works fine on the server, although not when run from Visual Studio.