# HttpHandler assembly name in ASP.NET Website type project

Tags: asp.net, .net, httphandler

How do you specify the assembly qualified type name of your HTTP Handlers in an ASP.NET *web site type project* because the assembly that the handler will be compiled into will be dynamically generated at run-time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Http-handler load error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168451/http-handler-load-error)

Answer (score 0):

You give the full namespace and assembly name like this....

```
MySite.MyHandler, MySite
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Comment: I know the syntax. The question is: how do you know the assembly name? The assembly name in a website type project is generated dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Ah ok, apologies - I misread the question. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168451/http-handler-load-error

Comment: Whoa! Thank you. That might just be the answer. I'll be able to try it out in 15 minutes. Now, instead of voting for the closure of the question, why don't you edit your answer from the correct answer to that question and I'll mark your answer as the right one since you pointed me to the right answer anyway.

Comment: Cool. I couldn't live with the guilt from leeching off someone else's answer ;)